# How to delete multiple records using php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax

I have multiple rows of news when I show them using php. I'm trying to remove multiple rows simultaneously using checkboxes next to each row.

This is my php code

```
<?
$select_news = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news order by time desc limit $x,$numbershownews");

            while ($rows_news = $select_news->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

            $id_news       = $rows_news ['id'];
            $title_news    = $rows_news ['title'];
        ?>
        <table>
        <tr rel="<? echo $id_news; ?>">

        <td class="tdtable" id="<? echo $id_news; ?>" width="4%">
        <input type="checkbox" rel="<? echo $id_news; ?>" name="checkbox[]" class="checkboxtable" value="<? echo $id_news; ?>">
        </td>
        <td class="tdtable" id="<? echo $id_news; ?>" width="50%">
        <? echo  $title_news; ?>
        </td>
        </tr
        </table
    <?
    }
    ?>
<button class="deletecheckednews">Delete</button>
```

and this is jquery code

```
$(".deletecheckednews").on( 'click', function () {

  var arr = new Array();

  $(".checkboxtable:checked").each(function () {
    arr.push($(this).attr("rel"));
  });

  if(arr == "") {
    alertify.error("no selected news"); 
  } else {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "action/delete_multiple_news.php",
      data: arr ,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alertify.success(data);

        $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
          $("tr[rel="+value+"]").fadeOut();
        });
      }
    });

  }

  return false
});
```

How can I pass this array on to "delete_multiple_news.php"? I have tried this `$checkedneww = $_REQUEST['arr'];`  and this `$checkedneww = $_POST['arr'];` but it doesn't work. How would I go about removing the selected rows?

Comment: `error_log(print_r($_POST,1));` so you can see what data structure you're dealing with.

Comment: I'll just drop this here as a bonus. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: what is `alertify.success(data);` mens in your code? and please show code of `delete_multiple_news.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a raw array in your ajax call (`data: arr`) but you're expecting a named variable (`$_POST['arr']`).

I'm not sure if `data: arr` is possible with jquery (haven't used it in years) but if it is, then the ids array you're looking for is simply  `$_POST` in its whole.

If that's not the case, or you want to do `$_POST['arr']` you should change your JS to `data: {arr: arr}`.

Answer (score 1):

On

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action/delete_multiple_news.php",
data: {"array_del": arr} , / <-
cache: false,
success: function(data){
alertify.success(data);
```

In PHP use

```
$array_del = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'array_del', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

If you wanna see the result, just do:

In PHP ajax:

```
$array_del = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'array_del', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo json_encode($array_del);
```

In js:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "action/delete_multiple_news.php",
data: arr ,
cache: false,
success: function(data){
alertify.success(data);
console.debug(data);
//$.each(arr, function(key, value) {
//    $("tr[rel="+value+"]").fadeOut();
//});

}
});
```

To delete you can use WHERE in sql to filter the results who you want delete example. If the results are more than one, you make a loop or a commun column.

```
$mysqli->query(DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column = $array_del[some_column]);
```